# Can I do a query based on multiple documents?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of documents where every document should have another, matching document. (This isn't by design, only for my current operation.) However, the current count for the number of documents in the collection is an odd number. Is there a way I can do a query on values of a key that aren't shared by one other document?

ie. if I have a collection like this:

```
{_id:'dcab0001', foo: 1, bar: 'dfgdgd'}
{_id:'dcab0002', foo: 2, bar: 'tjhttj'}
{_id:'dcab0003', foo: 1, bar: 'ydgdge'}
{_id:'dcab0004', foo: 3, bar: 'jyutkf'}
{_id:'dcab0005', foo: 3, bar: 'pofsth'}
```

I could do a query on `foo` that would return back the document with id `dcab0002`.

Comment: You could do that with map/reduce

Comment: Are you basically looking for all distinct() documents?

Comment: From what I understand, he wants only the document with foo=2, because it doesn't have a pair. He doesn't want to get documents which do have a pair.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this with MapReduce, or in MongoDB 2.2+ using the [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/).

Here's an example using the Aggregation Framework:

```
db.pairs.aggregate(

    // Group by values of 'foo' and count duplicates
    { $group: {
        _id: '$foo',
        key: { $push: '$_id' },
        dupes: { $sum: 1 }
    }},

    // Find the 'foo' values that are unpaired (odd number of dupes)
    { $match: {
        dupes: { $mod: [ 2, 1 ] }
    }}

    // Optionally, could add a $project to tidy up the output
)
```

Sample output:

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "key" : [
                "dcab0002"
            ],
            "dupes" : 1
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```